# Django 'objects.filter()' with list?

Tags: django, django-queryset

It is possible to limiting QuerySet in this kind of way:

```
creators_list = ['jane', 'tarzan', 'chita']
my_model.objects.filter(creator=creators_list)
```

???

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
my_model.objects.filter(creator__in=creator_list)
```

Docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

**EDIT**

This is now a bit outdated. If you run into problems with the original code, try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

my_filter_qs = Q()
for creator in creator_list:
    my_filter_qs = my_filter_qs | Q(creator=creator)
my_model.objects.filter(my_filter_qs)
```

There's probably a better way to do it but I'm not able to test it at the moment.

Comment: Assuming of course that the creator field is a CharField of some sort

Comment: @Bryce: Isn't the blessing of the Universe enough ;)?

Comment: Do You assuming that there is something more than Universe?

Comment: Thanks for link to django's docs Bryce. I written this but in the past and my knowledge is better in one part of django, because of time flowing but I want to learn something from people like You in stright way:)

Comment: @Chris perhaps there is more then one Universe and perhaps we are just part of some multiverse :p, you never know.

Comment: Multiworlds? Could be, perhaps. But what do You think about idea that everything is just a working computer? Diuglas Adams written in one of his book: "What is the meaning of life, Universe, and everything? 42" :D

Comment: I can't get `__in` to work with chars even when the field is a `CharField`. And according to the docs it only works with integers.

Comment: It might be outdated now as this was posted about 3 years ago but I'm not seeing anything in the docs where it says that it only works with integers. It even shows an example where it is using a subquery to dynamically find a list of strings and using those results as the lookup parameter. What does your query look like?

Comment: You may have to use a subquery like they show in the docs example.
`inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__contains='Ch').values('name')`
`entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__in=inner_qs)`

Answer (score 1):

Also if you're using sqlite and running into problems, there exists a limitation for the max number of items in the list.

```
def divideChunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

for slicerange in divideChunks(objs, 10):
        myobjects = my_model.objects.filter(creator__in = slicerange)
        ...
```

Comment: just a suggestion, never iterate on db... they have indexing and other features... that's why they are there for... they are not just array... way way more than that... this will dramatically reduce the performance... please check the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956422/10305444