# Filter by field with list data

Tags: python, django

I have a `file` field in a model that I want to filter with a list of file names. Let's say I have a file names `["wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip"]` (there are more but for the sake of example).

I tried the examples shown in [Django 'objects.filter()' with list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956391/django-objects-filter-with-list) but it doesn't seem to work.

**Example**

Using `Q()`

```py
from django.db.models import Q

# this is the example from the above link
my_filter_qs = Q()
for creator in ["wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip"]:
    my_filter_qs = my_filter_qs | Q(file=creator)

print(my_filter_qs)
a = request.user.data_storage.filter(my_filter_qs)
print(a.query)
# SELECT "data_store_datastoragemodel"."id", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."user_id", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_name", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."relative_path", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_added_datetime", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_updated_datetime", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_path" FROM "data_store_datastoragemodel" WHERE ("data_store_datastoragemodel"."user_id" = 3 AND "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file" = wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip)
print(a)
# <QuerySet []>
```

Using the `__in` I get the same output

```py
b = request.user.data_storage.filter(file__in=['wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip'])
print(b.query)
# SELECT "data_store_datastoragemodel"."id", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."user_id", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_name", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."relative_path", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_added_datetime", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_updated_datetime", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_path" FROM "data_store_datastoragemodel" WHERE ("data_store_datastoragemodel"."user_id" = 3 AND "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file" IN (wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip))
print(b)
# <QuerySet []>
```

But this works fine when I use `__contains`

```py
c = self.context['request'].user.data_storage.filter(file__contains='wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip')
print(c.query)
# SELECT "data_store_datastoragemodel"."id", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."user_id", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_name", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."relative_path", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_added_datetime", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_updated_datetime", "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file_path" FROM "data_store_datastoragemodel" WHERE ("data_store_datastoragemodel"."user_id" = 3 AND "data_store_datastoragemodel"."file"::text LIKE %wrist\_movement\_eeg\_no\_properties.zip%)
print(c)
# <QuerySet [<DataStorageModel: DataStorageModel object (7)>]>
```

If you look at the SQL query from the first and the third example, the only difference in them is the way `wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip` is denoted - `"data_store_datastoragemodel"."file" = wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip` (part of SQL query in the first example) and `"data_store_datastoragemodel"."file"::text LIKE %wrist\_movement\_eeg\_no\_properties.zip%` (part of SQL query in the third example).

I checked the type of contents in the list, and it showed that it was `str`. I am not sure what the difference is between the first and the third one but the first example is not working.

What am I doing wrong? Any explanation would be appreciated.

> Note that the `request` is the request variable from the views and I am calling the model when the user is logged in.

Comment: can you say what is the value of file attribute in the matched object in third one?

Comment: It's the location of the file

Comment: I mean value of it. Is it `wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip`?

Comment: yes, it's `wrist_movement_eeg_no_properties.zip`