# how can i pass a list to objects.get in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project using **Django / Rest Framework** I would like to know if there is any way
to pass a list  like that

```
mycontact = Contact.objects.get(id=[14,26,44,88])
```

instead of

```
mycontact = Contact.objects.get(id=14)
```

This is my full code :

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
def listin(self, request):
    mylist = List.objects.get(id=request.data['listId'])
    mycontact = Contact.objects.filter(id__in=[14,26,44,88])
    mycontact.list.add(mylist)
    return Response("Good")
```

i'm looking for a solution because I have manyTomanyField

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956422/12420884) answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Upload your models, Why does the Contact has property `list`?

Answer (score 1):

get accepts only one argument
If you want to pass a list of ids you can do this

```
mycontact = Contact.objects.filter(id__in=[14,26,44,88])  # this will return an iterable queryset
or
mycontact = list(Contact.objects.filter(id__in=[14,26,44,88]))  # this will return a list
```

Comment: @ramwin can you double check my question ( updated )

Answer (score 0):

Jay's answer is likely what you are looking for. But, in case you need an alternative

```py
contacts = [Contact.objects.get(id=id) for id in (14, 26, 44, 88)]
```

Comment: can you double check my question ( updated )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get()` for getting single unique object, for getting multiple id objects you can use `filter()`.

Try using below statement

`mycontact = Contact.objects.filter(id__in=[14,26,44,88])`

When you want to use list of parameters to find, can use `in` operator.

Comment: can you double check my question ( updated )

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your database table has too many records, consider using [in_bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk).

```py
mycontact = Contact.objects.in_bulk([14,26,44,88])
```

UPD:

In your case, loop through the `mycontact` queryset and set the `mylist` to each object:

```py
mylist = List.objects.get(id=request.data['listId'])
mycontact = Contact.objects.filter(id__in=[14,26,44,88])
for contact in mycontact:
    contact.list.add(mylist)
```

or simply do it vice-versa:

```py
mylist = List.objects.get(id=request.data['listId'])
mylist.contact_set.set([14,26,44,88])
```

Note: I used default related name `contact_set`

Comment: can you double check my question ( updated )